# Force SQLAlchemy to do type casting before session commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a very basic model in SQLAlchemy with sqlite (in reality it has a lot of fields):

```
class Board(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'board'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    rank = Column(Integer)
```

When I create new `Board` instances, I fill the `rank` field with an instance of either `str` or `unicode`. Regardless of the type, as long as the text holds a correct integer, the value is properly type-casted and saved in the database.

```
r1 = Board(
    board='United States of America',
    rank='555'
)

session = Session()
session.add(r1)
session.commit() # So far, so good
```

The weird thing in this example is that the `type` of `Board.rank` is `str` before the `commit`, and `int` afterwards, I would've assumed it'd be `int` from the beginning:

```
session.add(r1)
print type(r1.rank)  # <type 'str'>
session.commit()
print type(r1.rank)  # <type 'int'>
```

The question is: is it possible to have the type casting process triggered **before** issuing the commit? I need to work with the value of `Board.rank` as an `int` for other db-related tasks, so I'd like to leave the call to `session.commit` for the end.

P.S.: yes, I know I could just call `int(my_string)`, but in reality I have a lot of fields in my model and given that SQLAlchemy already does the type casting process, I'd rather take advantage of that.

Comment: SQLAlchemy does not do the type casting process; your database backend does it.